# WPF Button Change Image When Background Event Fires

Tags: xml, wpf

Very new to WPF and .NET in general. Previously I worked with winforms and VBA, very basic stuff.

I'm trying to learn how to utilize XAML and events. I know there are better ways to handle the following scenario, but I just want to understand the basics.

Imagine I have 2 buttons, connect and disconnect. When the window loads, Connect Has imgConnect, Disconnect has imgDisconnect. All the images are static resources

xaml

```
<Button x:Name="btnToolbarConnect" Content ="{StaticResource imgConnect}" ToolTip="Connect" Foreground="#FFF0F0F0" IsEnabled="True"/>
<Button x:Name="btnToolbarDisconnect" Content ="{StaticResource imgDisabledDisconnect}" ToolTip="Disconnect" Foreground="#FFF0F0F0" IsEnabled="False"/>
```

When a user presses connect (and successfully connects), the image on connect changes to imgDisabledConnect, and Disconnect changes to imgDisabledDisconnect (vice versa)

cs

```
 private void SystemSrv_ConnectionStateChanged(object sender, ConnectionStateChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            CheckServiceState();
        }

        
        private bool CheckServiceState()
        {
            try
            {
                
                switch (service.ReadState().State.ToString())
                {
                    case "Connected":
                       
                        return true;

                    case "Disconnected":
                        
                        return false;
                    default:
                        return true;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception err)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(err.Message);
                return false;
            }
        }
```

In the past, I would have addressed the UI elements (`text1.text.disable`) of a winform in the CheckServiceState switch statement, but to my knowledge, this isnt best practice with XAML/WPF (nor do I think it's possible for the button content image).

I have searched around here and other sites, but the only thing I can find is buttons firing their own events and changing their own images through XAML triggers/styles.

Basically im asking, in the most basic way, how do I change the image on one button when an event happens that isnt an event of it's own creation?

Once I get this figured out, I will play with styles and enable/disable many UI elements when this event fires.

==============Edit 1=============

Ive tried this, but the button Content doesnt change. Do I have to associate the binding TriggerTest somewhere else?

```
<Button x:Name="btnToolbarTcStart" Content = "New" ToolTip="Re/Start TwinCAT System" IsEnabled="False" Click="btnToolbarTcStart_Click">
                        <Button.Style>
                                <Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                                    <Style.Triggers>
                                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding TriggerTest}" Value="True">
                                            <Setter Property="Content" Value="{StaticResource TcStart}"/>
                                        </DataTrigger>
                                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding TriggerTest}" Value="False">
                                            <Setter Property="Content" Value="{StaticResource TcGrey}"/>
                                        </DataTrigger>
                                    </Style.Triggers>
                                </Style>
                            </Button.Style>
                        </Button>
```

CS

```
  private bool TriggerTest(bool value)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(value);
            return value;
        }
```

Comment: This one looks promising to me https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21788855/binding-an-image-in-wpf-mvvm

Comment: 1. you can't bind to method (`TriggerTest`), only to properties. make a property 2. if you have local value (`Content="New"`), then style setter won't be able to change it. so remove local value. recent example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71155514/how-to-dynamically-switch-staticresource-from-viewmodel

Comment: Do you have the option of loading the images in your ViewModel and binding them?

Answer (score 0):

> Basically im asking, in the most basic way, how do I change the image on one button when an event happens that isnt an event of it's own creation?

Just set the `Content` property more or less exactly like you did before:

```
btnToolbarConnect.Content = FindResource("imgDisabledDisconnect");
```

If you follow the recommended MVVM design pattern, you typically bind to a property of a view model and use a `DataTrigger` to set the `Content` based on its value like you have done in your edit. Just note that `TriggerTest` must be a *public property* of the current `DataContext` of the `Button` for your XAML markup to work as expected.

Comment: @GeneParmesan: Did you try this or what happended?